# Trying to find if a sub cstring exists inside a cstring

Tags: c++, c-strings

```
int myFind(const char * s, const char * b)
{
    int sSize = strlen(s);
    int bSize = strlen(b);
    int num = strcmp(s + 0, b + 0);

    for (int i = 1; i < bSize+1; ++i) {
        int correct;

        if (num == 0){
            num = strcmp(s+i,b+i);
            correct = correct + 1;
            cout << correct;

            if(correct == sSize){
                return i;
            }


        }
        if (num == -1 or num == 1){
            num = strcmp(s, b+i);
            correct = 0;
            if(correct < sSize and i < i - sSize){
                return -1;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is the function that is supposed to take two cstrings and see if the `s` cstring is anywhere in the `b` cstring.

If `s` is in `b` then it returns whatever i was at and if it isn't then it returns -1. My general logic is it runs through a for loop that stops after it has run through the entirety of `b`. `s` starts with its first letter, then if it's 0 it'll try its second letter and if it's not 0 then it'll stay on the first letter.

I hope that sort of made sense, this is a super convoluted function, but I'm trying to use what I got to work with, I would much rather just use `find` with strings, but that breaks my guidelines.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < bSize+1; ++i)` Remember that arrays are origin 0, so this loop is skipping the first character.

Comment: To avoid downvotes provide a complete and runnable example. The more we need to change to get your program running the more likely we are to introduce new bugs or accidentally fix existing ones. Both don't do you any good.

Comment: Get rid of all the `strcmp`s. They aren't doing you much good. `strcmp` always searches to the end of the string, so if A is ten characters and B is two characters, the only time you'll get a match is if  it exists in the last two characters of A.

Comment: Instead compare `A[start]` with `B[0]`. if there's a match compare `A[start+1]` with `B[1]`. when you get a mismatch advance `start` and begin comparing with `b[0]` again. This approach is brutal and slow, but will get you going.

Comment: Can't you just do `char *p = strstr(b,s); return p?p-b:-1;`?  Do you need to write your own?

Comment: What is your question? Is the code working? If it's not, what's its current wrong behavior?

Comment: user4581301, the for loop is set up that way because num is already equal to the two cstrings at 0. So when the for loop runs it starts at 1 and depending on the if statement itll become +1 instead of +0 initially. Also I really wish I could post the entire code, but I cant as it's part of a larger code that isnt unique to me. I will try start though, thank you

Comment: Jerry Jeremiah, I am not sure if I have too write it out, but I have not gone over strstr in lecture yet. So I would assume I cant use it, but I appreciate the help none the less.

Comment: user202729, The code compiles and works, but it's not returning what I want. I was basically asking how you would find an instance of a cstring inside another cstring and then I showed what I had so far, because logically my code should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

When this is production code, use `char *p = strstr(s,b); return p?p-s:-1;` as Jerry Jeremiah suggested.

When you want to do it with `strcmp`, than this will do the job:

```
int myFind(const char * s, const char * b)
{
  size_t sSize = strlen(s);
  size_t bSize = strlen(b);
  if (sSize >= bSize)
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= sSize - bSize; ++i)
    {
      if (!strncmp(&s[i], b, bSize))
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

I replaced `strcmp` with `strncmp`, it compares only given number of characters. In this case it's the length of b.

When this is your assignment about writing a searching algorithm and there was not mentioned to do it with `strcmp`, than you can look at pseudocode of this algorithm in your algorithms book and try to design it respectively. Or at `strstr` code in your compiler headers.

From your code I think you don't understand how C strings are represented in memory. They are zero terminated, for example `"aa"` is `aa0`. Strcmp says strings are equal, if they lengths are equal too. Thus if your first strcmp call (`int num = strcmp(s + 0, b + 0);`) returns zero, s and b are equal and you can return the result.

Your third call (`num = strcmp(s, b+i)`) will match the strings only when b is equal to the end part of s, for example `"aabb"` and `"bb"`, since `bb0` matches the end of `aabb0`.
But none ot the calls can match a string in the middle - `"aabba"` and `"bb"` will be `aabba0` and `bb0` and there is no match between these.

Comment: nevilad, so the second method worked for the most part. But it's not returning i for some reason. I think it's the second if loop, but im unsure. I'll keep trying to troubleshoot, but I appreciate the help.